# How can i use a value defined in the main() method in another method

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I was making a vending machine console application and couldnt pass the paymentAmount(amount of money input) into the second method to calculate the amount of change to be given.

Heres the code:

```
using System;

namespace Vending_Machine
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            //this is the variable i would like to use
            int itemClass, paymentAmount;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - 14) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Vending Machine V1");
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Insert your payment (value between 1 and 10)");
            paymentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to buy");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("1.Drinks \n2.Snacks \n3.Surprise Me!");
            itemClass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            switch (itemClass)
            {
                case 1:
                    Drinks();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Snacks();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Surprise();
                    break;
            }
        }
        public static void Drinks()
        {
            int drinkType, paymentChange;
            //this is where i would like to equate it to paymentChange
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("Which Drink would You like to Buy");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("1.Pepsi\n2.Coca-Cola\n3.Diet Coke\n4.Coca-Cola with Zesty Blood Orange\n5.Dasani\n6.Fanta\n7.Dr.Pepper\n8.Moxie\n9.Cold Coffee\n10.Red Bull");
            drinkType = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            switch (drinkType)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");
                    //this is where i would subtract the cost of the drink from the total and present it as change
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
                case 10:
                    Console.WriteLine("this will cost you $1\nPress any key to continue.");

                    break;
            }
        }
        public static void Snacks()
        {

        }
        public static void Surprise()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am a complete amatuer, so sorry for the basic question.

Edit: thank you for the help everyone. Its working now. Easiest way to do it was to pass the int as an argument. It was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c#, when you want method 2 to know some information that method 1 knows you add a parameters to the method 2 signature and then provide a value for that argument in method 1, when you call method 2:

```
public void Method1(){ //this method has no parameters

  int x = 5;

  Method2(x); passes the value of x, to method 2
}

public void Method2(int someNumber){ //this method has one, integer, parameter

  Console.Out.WritLine(someNumber); //prints out "5", which originally came from the value of x

}
```

It's important to note that Method2 doesn't get access to the `x` in Method1. If Method2 changes the value of `someNumber`, the value of `x` is unaffected. In simple terms we refer to this as "passing by value" - the value of x from Method1 is passed into method 2, not the actual variable. You could think of it like, as soon as method 2 is called, c# runs this line: `int someNumber = 5` -> it's established another variable called someNumber, and got the value from the value x was but they are clearly unrelated - they just happen to have the same value

If we were passing something more complex, like larger object, then we could change things about the object, and Method1 would see the changes, but we still couldn't swap it out for a whole new object and have Method1 see that change, unless it was passed with the ref or out keywords. In general, we refer to this as "passing by reference" but it's a bit of an off phrase because things are always variable references. These are definitely concepts to return to another time though (later, when you've got a bit more coding experience and youre totally on board with some of the basic concepts)

For now, while passing simple things like ints, know that changing the value in Method2 won't affect the value in Method1. If Method1 needs to know what Method2 changed a value to, then2ethod 2 should return the value to Method1:

```
public void Method1(){ //this method has no parameters

  int x = 5;

  int newX = Method2(x); passes the value of x, to method 2. newX will be set to 10 when Method2 finishes
}

public int Method2(int someNumber){ //this method has one, integer, parameter

  return someNumber + 5; //returns 10 back to the calling method, Method1

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make functions drinks, snacks and surprise in that way that they accept a parameter. Something like this:

```
public void drinks(int paymentAmount) {
    //some logic here
}
```

Then you call that function inside main like this:

```
public static void Main() {
   int paymentAmount;
   paymentAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   drinks(paymentAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To declare argument for a method, add in the parentheses a list of type and arguments name :

```
public static int MyMethod(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

You can call it by passing a list of matching type.

```
Console.WriteLine(MyMethod(3, 5)); // print out 8
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd pass that variable as an argument instead of calling that variable directly. 
Use your variable as your argument for the second method `Drinks`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to SO. A more complete answer including a code example would get you more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the variables on the class level.

Example :

```
using System;

namespace Vending_Machine
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int itemClass;
        private static int paymentAmount;
        private static int drinkType;
        private static int paymentChange;

        public static void Main() {...}

        public static void Drinks() {...}

        public static void Snacks(){...}

        public static void Surprise(){...}
    }
}
```

this way, you will be able to use the variables across Vending_Machine's methods.